# Searching for a source table in search criteria in Source analyser in Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

This may be a naive question, but I am stuck on this simple one. I have to import a specific source table from the source database. I could see only a few schemas and not all (as there are thousands of), hence could not select desired table, so I am specifying the table in search box. But it does not show up anything. I tried using schema.tablename and different combinations but in vain. 
Infact, when I try searching for the tables that are already visible, they doesn't show up. Where am I going wrong in searching for a specific table? ANy help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Import Tables* dialog window change *Onwer name* to the name of the schema that contains the table.

The *Select tables* tree view shows tables from a single schema specified in *Onwer name* field and, by default, this value is set to the username used to establish the connection.